# "dice" contract "withdraw" action problem

Tags: smart-contract, permissions, inline-action

I wonder if anyone experienced a similar problem and managed to resolve it.

I'm testing the "dice" contract on my local tesnet. I've setup up all necessary contracts and could deposit assets to the "dice" contract, but when I try to withdraw funds, that is, invoke "withdraw" action, I get the following error:

```
Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
```

And here are messages from nodeos:

```
2757860ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
2757860ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3090003 unsatisfied_authorization: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"dice","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"dice","permission":"eosio.code"}], and provided keys []
    {"auth":{"actor":"dice","permission":"active"},"provided_delay":0,"provided_permissions":[{"actor":"dice","permission":"eosio.code"}],"provided_keys":[],"delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000}
    thread-0  authorization_manager.cpp:409 check_authorization
{"_pending_console_output.str()":""}
thread-0  apply_context.cpp:62 exec_one
```

[setup_dice.txt](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/files/2108454/setup_dice.txt) - script to setup "dice" contract (all keys are uploaded to the wallet and it is unlocked)
I'm testing this on the EOS v1.0.5, but the same was for v1.0.2

I'm not sure if this is an EOS core problem, or "dice" contract has incorrect implementation or its description [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/v1.0.5/contracts/dice) is outdated.

There is also issue [#4166](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4166) I opened on the GitHub describing this problem.

**UPDATE:**
This problem was solved according to [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4166#issuecomment-400234072) answer on GitHub

Comment: First,  'eosio.code' was definitely wrong. Change to 'active'. Let's take a look at the next problem.

Comment: Show the error after doing this.

Comment: After suggested change, I get error on "deposit" action, which was working previously.     transaction declares authority '{"actor":"alice","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"dice","permission":"eosio.code"}], and provided keys []
    {"auth":{"actor":"alice","permission":"active"},"provided_delay":0,"provided_permissions":[{"actor":"dice","permission":"eosio.code"}],"provided_keys":[],"delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000}
    thread-0  authorization_manager.cpp:409 check_authorization

Comment: My permission command is     -  cleos set account permission alice active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS5UN5TzsSFSfbdX48MeZrGEywYLPzXNbXd6vbf2frVSsdKp6g1C","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"dice","permission":"active"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p alice@active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as explained in the message,

you need to add 'eosio.code' permission to dice@active

cleos set account permission dice active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS7ijWCBmoXBi3CgtK7DJxentZZeTkeUnaSDvyro9dq7Sd1C3dC4","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"dice","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p dice

Comment: I'd like to thank you very much, and I want to know if it is a common solution?